# $4D$ rotations and quaternions

Tags: geometry, quaternions, rotations

I have a question about $4D$ rotation:
I programmed a little $4D$ game and I used the classical hyper-sphere coordinates, to rotate a vector.

It works, but it has some problems:
(just for clarity I take the cartesian coordinates, translate in hypersphere coordinates, add the angle I wish than translate back to cartesian)
This procedure causes jumble locks and approximation errors.

I'm asking you if it is possible like in $3D$ to have quaterinions to manage the rotations?

I'll prefer not to use rotation matrix, which has other problems:

Thanks in advance for the help!
If you want to have a look at the game:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IUnqm8j4BE
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaeqUp3jbls

Comment: Yes. You can use two quaternions. One acts on the space of all quaternions by left multiplication and the other acts by right multiplication.

Comment: Here are two related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/40088 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/24739

Comment: thank you Theo! the guy really explained it well, I'll try to translate it in my program and if I have other question I'll come back here

Comment: For more on what Qiaochu is referring to, see the Wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space#Algebra_of_4D_rotations

Comment: I was going to ask this same question mysef, but my previous questions were quoted as references! I am using 4x4 matrix for rotations, but I was looking for something less resource intensive, like quaternions...